# C# DotLiquid Simple Example Unit Test not working as expected

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, template-engine, liquid

I have been wanting to use the great DotLiquid and tried to following example (written by myself) without any major success.

```
internal class AuthorDrop : Drop {
    private String lname;

    public String ToGive { get { return lname; } }


    public AuthorDrop(String t) {
        lname = t;
    }
}
```

with the corresponding test

```
[Test]
    public void TestFirstStep() {
       Template tpl = Template.Parse("hi {{ author2.togive }}");  
       Console.WriteLine(tpl.Render(Hash.FromAnonymousObject(new { author2 = new AuthorDrop("Test 123") }))); 
    }
```

However, this leades to the output

> hi

instead of hi Test 123.

Can anyone help me figure out what's going on here?

Thank you so much in advance,

--
Chris

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By default DotLiquid uses Ruby's naming convention for methods and properties. In your example ToGive is "renamed" as to_give.
If you prefer you can instead use C# naming convention by setting the static propery `DotLiquid.Template.NamingConvention = new DotLiquid.NamingConventions.CSharpNamingConvention();`

HTH